# Drush make SVN repository

Tags: drush, installation-profiles

I want to add a checkout of an SVN project in the .make file. However, the checkout only concerns a specific folder (new profile added). Has anyone made this before ?

edit : Folder and not file. My bad.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "concerns a specific file". A Drupal install profile is an entire directory, not one file. I have successfully use drush make with subversion to checkout a project such as a theme or module.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. It was about a subdirectory and not a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do a svn export (unless you provide the --working-copy flag to drush) into `DRUPAL_ROOT/profiles/contrib/myprofile`

Drush make old-style syntax:

```
projects[myprofile][type] = profile
projects[myprofile][download][type] = svn
projects[myprofile][download][url] = svn+ssh://example.com/svn/path/to/subdirectory/of/myprofile
; This would place the checkout into /profiles/contrib/myprofile
projects[myprofile][subdir] = "contrib"
```

Drush make YAML syntax:

```
projects:
    myprofile:
        type: "profile"
        download:
            type: svn
            url: "svn+ssh://example.com/svn/path/to/subdirectory/of/myprofile"
        subdir: "contrib"
```

The drush make documentation is now located at http://www.drush.org/en/master/make.